# Compromised facebook account always send password recovery to compromised email

Tags: facebook

My friend's facebook account has been compromised, both email and phone has been changed.

Now, I wish to help him to recover it, however it seems there's a loop in facebook's recovery protocol:

Step1: https://www.facebook.com/hacked

[image]

Step2: click on "My Account Is Compromised" button:

[image]

Step3: fill out the "old password" and click "Continue":

[image]

"Try again" button drops me back to Step2.

So I click on "Secure My Account":

[image]

Now, as "m**6@gmail.com" is not belonging to him, he obviously can't access the recovery link.

I wish to help him to provide his ID to facebook to regain his account, but I couldn't find any way where can he upload/send his ID for authentication.

How can we do it?

Comment: I have bad news in my experience with Facebook, you need an account to contact support, and if your question has something to do with your account that prevents you from logging into you are essentially out of luck. Case in point, I opened an account, and within 6 hours it was closed for policy violations.  Essentially based what I determine that profile didn't appear real, except when I opted to appeal that decision and send a photo of myself, they denied my appeal.  Well once you appeal the decision, it's final, leaving you with no way to appeal their decision.